# Не подгружается layout.xml в Magento

Tags: xml, magento, layout

Делаю модуль для Magento и, как я понял, не подгружается layout. В файле `\app\code\local\***\Brands\etc\config.xml` есть такой код:

```
http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_13kb.1405504585.jpg

\app\design\frontend\***\default\layout\brand.xml

http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_37kb.1405504773.jpg
```

Но файл `brand.xml` не подгружается и если в нем сделать ошибку, то ничего не изменяется. В контролере выполняю такой код

```
http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_16kb.1405504852.jpg
```

И вижу:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function assign() on a non-object in...

Comment: Покажите полностью etc/config.xml

Answer (score 2):

Ругается на `assign()`, потому что `getBlock('brand-list')` отдает пустоту. делаем вывод, что блока `brand-list` не существует или контроллер не может найти `brand.xml`

Просмотрите `config.xml`

```
<routers>
  <Netpeak_Brands>
    <use>standard</use>
    <args>
      <module>Netpeak_Brands</module>
      <frontName>brand</frontName>
    </args>
  </Netpeak_Brands>
</routers>
<layout>
  <updates>
    <Netpeak_Brands>
      <file>brand.xml</file>
    </Netpeak_Brands>
  </updates>
</layout>
```

И положите свой `layout` в

```
\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\
```